# Request urlencoded body is empty in express

Tags: node.js, express, x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm trying to get url parameters in express 4.17.3 using the urlencoded middleware but the body is always empty, I reproducted it to a minimal code:

```
const express = require("express");

(()=>{
    const app  = express();
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    
    app.get("/", async(req, res)=>{
        console.log(req.body); //always print '{}'
        res.send();
    });
    
    app.listen(83, ()=>{
        console.log("test app listening on port 83");
    })
})();
```

Here's my request

```
http://localhost:83/?param1=42
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: URL parameters are in the URL, not the body. Use `req.query`.

Comment: @tkausl req.query properties are raw strings and I can't use arrays as value, according to the documentation I can use this middleware to parse the parameters as a body-like object as with the express.json() parser: https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#express.urlencoded

Answer (score 1):

A few things to break down. To answer your question to get params you can use
`req.query` so your code would be:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query)
  res.send()
})
```

Addressing `urlencoded` it should be changed from:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

to:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

good habit to not hard code the `port` so the line of code:

```
app.listen(83, ()=>{
  console.log("test app listening on port 83");
})
```

should be:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 83

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`test app listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

full working code example:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 83

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query)
  res.send()
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`test app listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

When using express I also like to implement [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) and if you add this to your *package.json*:

```
"dev": "nodemon node index.js"
```

then in the terminal you can run:

```
npm run dev
```

you wont have to restart your server during development changes.

Comment: The port is not hardcoded in my real project, it was just a fast snippet to isolate the problem and I'm using nodemon too ;) 
I don't get the point of using the urlencoded middleware if I'm just using the "vanilla" req.body object